# Bootstrap navbar breaking in two rows issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, nav

**1st problem :**

I'm trying to make a navbar in one row, however, it breaks in two rows even if there is enough space. I don't want to include the *Sign in* button in the *collapse navbar-collapse* div.

Here's what i got :

https://jsfiddle.net/fsjowxqn/

**2nd problem :**

I want my navbar to stay visible even if the user scrolls down, i added the *navbar-static-top* class like this :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
```

but it doesn't seem to be working.

any help would be appreciated. Thank's in advance.

Comment: I believe the class for a fixed top navbar is navbar-fixed-top. Check out [bootstrap's example elements](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/).

Comment: **2nd problem** solved, thank's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add navbar-left to the collapse nav div

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```

Add sign_in class to your sign in button parent

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right sign_in">
```

and then add the following css

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .sign_in {
    position: absolute;
    right: 100px;
    top: -7px;
  }
}
```

hope it works for your scenario

Comment: thank's it works !!
however no need for adding `navbar-left` to the collapse nav div
and the `top: -7px;`

Answer (score 0):

You have place your last button in the wrong div  (see ****move here****)

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Homepage <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Forum <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
        <li><a href="#">Become a Moderator</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><!-- *****move here *****-->
      <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn">Sign in</button></li>
      </ul>      
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
```

ANd for Second question

and for fixed  use navbar-fixed-top

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

Comment: thank's for reply, but as i said I don't want to include the _Sign in_ button in the _collapse navbar-collapse_ div . So i did it on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sign in button should be neasted with some element in your nav, like the navbar-header or the container. Like this for example:
2. Change **navbar-static-top** by **navbar-fixed-top**:

Here is your JSFiddle i've updated: https://jsfiddle.net/Pontual/fsjowxqn/3/

```
<div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn">Sign in</button></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Ok , it looks better, but i want the button to be at the right. That's what i was trying to do actually..

Comment: I've updated the jsfiddle and worked fine using <button type="button" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn pull-right">. You can check the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Pontual/fsjowxqn/6/

Comment: It works only when the div is collapsed, try to enlarge the output window to see that it still doesn't work. Also, i want the Sign in button to be at the right, in your jsfiddle, it's still in the left of the "show menu" button.